How is bandwidth used in ROS2?
I am developing a multi robot system, where each robot publishes its status to ROS bridge. Robots also have a LiDAR which is always on. Will this use bandwidth on the network, even if I am not subscribed to the LiDAR topic on the server? or will the LiDAR data be sent locally causing no network load

The ROS bridge server is running on the same machine as the LIDAR driver, any communication between the two will only cause data exchange locally.
When you connect to the ROS bridge server over a network, the data will use bandwidth on that network. Only the topics that you subscribe to, are transmitted. So if you do not subscribe to the LIDAR data, it will not be transmitted.
As far as I understand, the ROS bridge doesn't subscribe to the LIDAR topic until you subscribe to that topic through the ROS bridge server.

Hi, thanks for the answer. Just to clarify, the ROS bridge server is connected over a network but is not subscribed to the LIDAR topic. So the bandwidth on the network is not used for the LiDAR data? (Bandwidth is used only for topics ROS Bridge is subscribed to)
